# Matlab, why is strel non-semetrical with respect to the angle?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was attempting to apply a closing operation to an image using a line structuring element at 8 different directions. Initially I wanted to apply it to angles in the range `[0 .. 360]` but I later realised that my stucturing element is symmetrical so I thought of using the range `[0 .. 180]` instead. However, I later realized that Matlab's structuring element function (strel) does not produce symmetrical results for angles that are 180 degrees apart. Consider:

```
>> strel('line', 11, 120)

ans =

Flat STREL object containing 9 neighbors.

Neighborhood:
     1     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     0     0     0     1


>>
```

And:

```
>> strel('line', 11, 300)

ans =

Flat STREL object containing 9 neighbors.

Neighborhood:
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
```

I expect that the 2 structuring elements above should be symmetrical, since `300 = 120 + 180`. Why is this not the case for Matlab's `strel` function?

Comment: it is just an approximation. I would not expect exactly the same results. increase or decrease on of your angles a bit, I'm sure you will get the same result at some point. If you really want to know why you should contact Mathworks and ask them. i doubt to many of us have seen their source code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Potatoes:

This is an interesting observation. If you happen to look into the implementation of the `strel` object in MATLAB, the lines to observe are these (in the MakeLineStrel sub-function):

```
theta = theta_d * pi / 180;
x = round((len-1)/2 * cos(theta));
y = -round((len-1)/2 * sin(theta));
```

The `theta_d` value is the angle in degrees you've specified, and `len` is the length of the line you've requested for.

The values for `x` and `y` define the integer valued "end point" of the line, and the structuring element is constructed such that it is symmetric with respect to the origin.

Due to the rounding operation here, when you specify `120` for `theta_d`, the pair `(x,y)` will be `(-2, -4)`, but when you specify `300`, `(x,y)` will be `(3, 4)`. This is the root cause for the discretized line being different due to the way the angles have been represented.

Given this understanding, it would be safest to actually print the neighborhood of the structuring element and ensure that it looks right, before using it in your operation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks; any clue what approach we could use to write a custom strel function that is symmetrical?

Comment: potatoes: I think a good way to get around this is to pass in angles that are inside the `[0 180]` range. Maybe mod(angle, 180) before passing it into `strel`? The problem really is that there is no single right answer, as we are approximating a discrete line.